# Graphics2D wrapper for 2d game engine

Tags: java, inheritance, graphics2d

I'm trying to write a 2d game engine and I'm trying to implement a viewport system so that when I'm drawing in a certain viewport, the game coordinates will be transformed to the screen coordinates without having to manually do the transformation.

What I want to do is create a `Graphics2D` wrapper that adds a `setViewport` method.

The way I see it there are 2 options:

1. Create a class that has an instance of a `Graphics2D` and has all the same methods as `Graphics2D` plus `setViewport` and just calls the respective method on the `Graphics2D` instance.
2. Subclass `Graphics2D` and just add a `setViewport` method and then just cast from `Graphics2D` to this new class

I tried #2 because #1 seemed very impractical but ran into a `ClassCastException`. I'm unable to cast `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` to this new class. When I print the graphics object before the cast (either `Graphics` or `Graphics2D`), both come out as `sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D`.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong trying to subclass and cast? If not, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think that any solution that tries to subclass Graphics2D is going to work very well.

Comment: I'm following along the slides from a college class (not actually taking the class) and they say "Create a wrapper for Graphics2D with a method like setViewport() – When drawing a viewport, toggle a flag inside your Graphics2D wrapper that you need to transform game->screen coordinates whenever a shape is drawn – Do separate game object transforms in each object’s own onDraw() call – Unmark your wrapper when finished drawing the viewport"  Is there some other interpretation of wrapper?

Comment: Interesting -- do you have a link to this slide collection?

Comment: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs1971/lectures.shtml The lecture this is in is the second one in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: "*Is there some other interpretation of wrapper?*" A wrapper is a class that holds the wrapped class as a member (a field). It's composition.

Comment: What I've done for now (and this solution is open to change) is exactly that. I've created a new class that contains a Graphics2D object, and just transfers all the method calls to that object (took a little while to write in all the methods). This way I can add whatever methods I need like the setViewport() one described in the question. It does seem like there should be a simpler/more elegant way to create this functionality though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One OO design priciple is *"favor composition over inheritance"*, this is acheived using the **wrapper class** or **Decorator** design pattern (which is in my opinion what is meant by wrapper in the course slide). So what you have done is in fact the *elegant* solution for a number of reasons:

- It protects against future implementation changes in `Graphics2D`, if you use inheritance and by misfortune a new method is added to `Graphics2D` with the same signature as your new method and a different return type, your class will no longer compile. If you use the same signature and return type you would override the new method in `Graphics2D` which could (and has) result in several days of frustrating debugging.
- Inheritance in this way **violates** encapsulation making software fragile and error-prone in the long run.
- Using composition you are protecting your class from future changes in the class your *composing* with, your class would *forward* all method calls to it's `private` `Graphics2D` instance and handle transforming coordinates separately.
- It also allows for easy future extension, using inheritance will tie you to the current implementation of `Graphics2D` potentially limiting the performance of your class.

An example of this exists in the Java API: The `Properties` class extends `HashTable`, this illustrates improper use of inheritance because a `Properties` *is not* a `HashTable`, it's not meant to be used in the same way. In this case a call to `Properties p.getProperty(key)` might give different results than `p.get(key)`, because the latter-case does not take defaults into account.

The **Decorator** design pattern:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private WrappedClass w;

    public Wrapper(WrappedClass w) {
       this.w = w;  
    }

    // Forward calls to WrappedClass methods to the private instance.
    public ReturnType example(Argument a) { return w.example(a); }

    // Add your methods here:
}
```

Although this might seem like a tedious approach it is worth it in the long run for the reasons above. Also the existance of interfaces in the Java API such as the `Set` interface for the `HashSet` above makes writing such classes easier although I don't know if such an interface exists for `Graphics2D`.

sources: Effective Java 2nd Edition - Joshua Bloch

Comment: +1 and accepted for providing the logical reasoning behind this kind of design decision. It definitely leaves the door open in terms of adding more functionality on top of the basic Graphics2D. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I created a coordinate system for a game that I wrote.  Feel free to use these classes as examples.

Here's the CoordinateSystem class.

```
package com.ggl.game.utilities;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 * <p>
 * This class creates a Cartesian and Polar coordinate system to overlay a Swing
 * drawing area (usually a <code>JPanel</code>). The user of the class sets a
 * limit as to how far the X axis or the Y axis extends in the negative and
 * positive direction from (0, 0). Point (0, 0) will be placed in the center of
 * the drawing area.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Since the drawing area is usually not square, the limit applies to the
 * shorter dimension. The actual limits can be retrieved from this class, and
 * will change if the user of the application changes the drawing area size by
 * maximizing or normalizing the application <code>JFrame</code> window.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Using a Cartesian or Polar coordinate system frees the user of this class
 * from having to worry about Swing pixel coordinates.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author Gilbert G. Le Blanc
 * @version 1.0 - 23 February 2015
 * 
 * @see com.ggl.game.utilities.Polar2D
 * @see java.awt.geom.Point2D
 * @see javax.swing.JFrame
 * @see javax.swing.JPanel
 */
public class CoordinateSystem {

    private double conversionFactor;
    private double xLimit;
    private double yLimit;

    private int height;
    private int width;

    /**
     * <p>
     * This creates a Cartesian and Polar coordinate system over a Swing drawing
     * area (usually a <code>JPanel</code>). If the drawing area is square, the
     * X axis extends from -limit to limit and the Y axis extends from -limit to
     * limit.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * If the drawing area is not square, then the smaller dimension, either X
     * or Y, extends from -limit to limit. The larger dimension extends beyond
     * the limit in both directions.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Since most displays are not square, the X and Y axis will usually have
     * different limits.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param limit
     *            - The limit of the X and Y axis in a Cartesian coordinate
     *            system.
     * @param width
     *            - The width of the drawing area in pixels.
     * @param height
     *            - The height of the drawing area in pixels.
     */
    public CoordinateSystem(double limit, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        if (width > height) {
            this.xLimit = limit * width / height;
            this.yLimit = limit;
            this.conversionFactor = (limit + limit) / (double) height;
        } else if (width < height) {
            this.xLimit = limit;
            this.yLimit = limit * height / width;
            this.conversionFactor = (limit + limit) / (double) width;
        } else {
            this.xLimit = limit;
            this.yLimit = limit;
            this.conversionFactor = (limit + limit) / (double) width;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method changes the drawing area dimension, along with the X and Y
     * axis limits.
     * 
     * @param dimension
     *            - A <code>Dimension</code> with the new drawing area
     *            dimension.
     */
    public void setDrawingSize(Dimension dimension) {
        setDrawingSize(dimension.width, dimension.height);
    }

    /**
     * This method changes the drawing area width and height, along with the X
     * and Y axis limits.
     * 
     * @param width
     *            - The width of the drawing area in pixels.
     * @param height
     *            - The height of the drawing area in pixels.
     */
    public void setDrawingSize(int width, int height) {
        xLimit = xLimit / this.width * width;
        yLimit = yLimit / this.height * height;

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the Cartesian coordinate limit for the X axis.
     * 
     * @return The Cartesian coordinate limit for the X axis.
     */
    public double getxLimit() {
        return xLimit;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the Cartesian coordinate limit for the Y axis.
     * 
     * @return The Cartesian coordinate limit for the Y axis.
     */
    public double getyLimit() {
        return yLimit;
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Polar coordinate distance and theta angle in
     * radians to a pixel location on a drawing area.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            - A Polar coordinate distance
     * @param theta
     *            - A Polar coordinate theta angle in radians
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertPolarToPixels(double distance, double theta) {
        return convertToPixels(new Polar2D.Double(distance, theta));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Cartesian coordinate x and y to a pixel location
     * on a drawing area.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            - A Cartesian coordinate x.
     * @param y
     *            - A Cartesian coordinate y.
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertPointToPixels(double x, double y) {
        return convertToPixels(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Polar coordinate to a pixel location on a drawing
     * area.
     * 
     * @param polar
     *            - A Polar coordinate.
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertToPixels(Polar2D polar) {
        double x = polar.getDistance() * Math.cos(polar.getTheta());
        double y = polar.getDistance() * Math.sin(polar.getTheta());
        return convertToPixels(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Cartesian coordinate to a pixel location on a
     * drawing area.
     * 
     * @param cartesian
     *            - A Cartesian coordinate.
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertToPixels(Point2D cartesian) {
        int x = (int) Math
                .round((cartesian.getX() + xLimit) / conversionFactor);
        int y = (int) Math.round((-cartesian.getY() + yLimit)
                / conversionFactor);
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Cartesian
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            - The x pixel location.
     * @param y
     *            - The y pixel location.
     * @return A Cartesian coordinate.
     */
    public Point2D convertToCartesian(int x, int y) {
        return convertToCartesian(new Point(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Cartesian
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param point
     *            - The pixel location.
     * @return A Cartesian coordinate.
     */
    public Point2D convertToCartesian(Point point) {
        double x = (double) point.x * conversionFactor - xLimit;
        double y = (double) -point.y * conversionFactor + yLimit;
        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Polar
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            - The x pixel location.
     * @param y
     *            - The y pixel location.
     * @return A Polar coordinate.
     */
    public Polar2D convertToPolar(int x, int y) {
        return convertToPolar(new Point(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Polar
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param point
     *            - The pixel location.
     * @return A Polar coordinate.
     */
    public Polar2D convertToPolar(Point point) {
        double x = (double) point.x * conversionFactor - xLimit;
        double y = (double) -point.y * conversionFactor + yLimit;
        double distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double theta = Math.atan2(y, x);
        return new Polar2D.Double(distance, theta);
    }

}
```

And here's the Polar2D class.  It's a clone of the Point2D class.

```
package com.ggl.game.utilities;

/**
 * The <code>Polar2D</code> class defines a point representing a location in
 * distance, theta angle coordinate space.
 * <p>
 * This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D
 * coordinate. The actual storage representation of the coordinates is left to
 * the subclass.
 * 
 * @version 1.0 - 23 February 2015
 * @author Jim Graham (author of Point2D), Gilbert Le Blanc
 */
public abstract class Polar2D implements Cloneable {
    /**
     * The <code>Float</code> class defines a point specified in float
     * precision.
     */
    public static class Float extends Polar2D {
        /**
         * The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public float distance;
        /**
         * The theta angle of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public float theta;

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with coordinates
         * (0,&nbsp;0).
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Float() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with the specified
         * coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set the newly constructed
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set the newly
         *            constructed <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Float(float distance, float theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getDistance() {
            return (double) distance;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getTheta() {
            return (double) theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getThetaInDegrees() {
            double degrees = 180D / Math.PI * theta;
            return (degrees < 0D) ? degrees + 360D : degrees;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
         * <code>double</code> distance and theta angle in radians.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set this <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set this
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public void setLocation(double distance, double theta) {
            this.distance = (float) distance;
            this.theta = (float) theta;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
         * <code>float</code> coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set this <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set this
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public void setLocation(float distance, float theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a <code>String</code> that represents the value of this
         * <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @return A <code>String</code> representation of this
         *         <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Polar2D.Float[" + distance + ", " + theta + "]";
        }
    }

    /**
     * The <code>Double</code> class defines a point specified in
     * <code>double</code> precision.
     */
    public static class Double extends Polar2D {
        /**
         * The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public double distance;
        /**
         * The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public double theta;

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with (0,&nbsp;0)
         * distance and theta angle in radians.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Double() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with the specified
         * coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set the newly constructed
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set the newly
         *            constructed <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Double(double distance, double theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getTheta() {
            return theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return The theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getThetaInDegrees() {
            double degrees = 180D / Math.PI * theta;
            return (degrees < 0D) ? degrees + 360D : degrees;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
         * <code>double</code> coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set this <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set this
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public void setLocation(double distance, double theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a <code>String</code> that represents the value of this
         * <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @return A <code>String</code> representation of this
         *         <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Polar2D.Double[" + distance + ", " + theta + "]";
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is an abstract class that cannot be instantiated directly.
     * Type-specific implementation subclasses are available for instantiation
     * and provide a number of formats for storing the information necessary to
     * satisfy the various accessor methods below.
     * 
     * @see java.awt.geom.Polar2D.Float
     * @see java.awt.geom.Polar2D.Double
     * @see java.awt.Point
     */
    protected Polar2D() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code> in <code>double</code>
     * precision.
     * 
     * @return The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract double getDistance();

    /**
     * Returns the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
     * <code>double</code> precision.
     * 
     * @return The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract double getTheta();

    /**
     * Returns the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
     * <code>double</code> precision.
     * 
     * @return The theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract double getThetaInDegrees();

    /**
     * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
     * <code>double</code> coordinates.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @param theta
     *            The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract void setLocation(double distance, double theta);

    /**
     * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the same coordinates as
     * the specified <code>Polar2D</code> object.
     * 
     * @param p
     *            the specified <code>Polar2D</code> the which to set this
     *            <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public void setLocation(Polar2D p) {
        setLocation(p.getDistance(), p.getTheta());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the distance between two points.
     * 
     * @param distance1
     *            The distance of the first point
     * @Parm theta1 The theta angle in radians of the first point
     * @param distance2
     *            The distance of the second point
     * @param theta2
     *            The theta angle in radians of the second point
     * @return The square of the distance between the two specified points.
     */
    public static double distanceSq(double distance1, double theta1,
            double distance2, double theta2) {
        double x1 = distance1 * Math.cos(theta1);
        double y1 = distance1 * Math.sin(theta1);
        double x2 = distance2 * Math.cos(theta2);
        double y2 = distance2 * Math.sin(theta2);
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance between two points.
     * 
     * @param distance1
     *            The distance of the first point
     * @param theta1
     *            The theta angle in radians of the first point
     * @param distance2
     *            The distance of the second point
     * @param theta2
     *            The theta angle in radians of the second point
     * @return The distance between the two specified points.
     */
    public static double distance(double distance1, double theta1,
            double distance2, double theta2) {
        double x1 = distance1 * Math.cos(theta1);
        double y1 = distance1 * Math.sin(theta1);
        double x2 = distance2 * Math.cos(theta2);
        double y2 = distance2 * Math.sin(theta2);
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a
     * specified point.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            The distance of the specified point
     * @param theta
     *            The theta angle in radians of the specified point
     * @return The square of the distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> and
     *         the specified point.
     */
    public double distanceSq(double distance, double theta) {
        double x1 = distance * Math.cos(theta);
        double y1 = distance * Math.sin(theta);
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a
     * specified <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * 
     * @param pt
     *            The specified <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @return The square of the distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> to a
     *         specified <code>Polar2D</code>.
     */
    public double distanceSq(Polar2D pt) {
        double x1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.cos(pt.getTheta());
        double y1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.sin(pt.getTheta());
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a specified point.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            The distance of the specified point
     * @param theta
     *            The theta angle in radians of the specified point
     * @return The distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> and a specified
     *         point.
     */
    public double distance(double distance, double theta) {
        double x1 = distance * Math.cos(theta);
        double y1 = distance * Math.sin(theta);
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a specified
     * <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * 
     * @param pt
     *            the specified <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @return The distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> and the specified
     *         <code>Polar2D</code>.
     */
    public double distance(Polar2D pt) {
        double x1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.cos(pt.getTheta());
        double y1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.sin(pt.getTheta());
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new object of the same class and with the same contents as this
     * object.
     * 
     * @return a clone of this instance.
     * @exception OutOfMemoryError
     *                if there is not enough memory.
     * @see java.lang.Cloneable
     * @since 1.7
     */
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the hash code for this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * 
     * @return a hash code for this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        long bits = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getDistance());
        bits ^= java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getTheta()) * 31;
        return (((int) bits) ^ ((int) (bits >> 32)));
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether or not two points are equal. Two instances of
     * <code>Polar2D</code> are equal if the values of their <code>x</code> and
     * <code>y</code> member fields, representing their position in the
     * coordinate space, are the same.
     * 
     * @param obj
     *            an object to be compared with this <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @return <code>true</code> if the object to be compared is an instance of
     *         <code>Polar2D</code> and has the same values; <code>false</code>
     *         otherwise.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Polar2D) {
            Polar2D p2d = (Polar2D) obj;
            return (getDistance() == p2d.getDistance())
                    && (getTheta() == p2d.getTheta());
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gilbert, thanks for your reply and 1+ for your efforts and interest. For the bounty though I'm looking for a canonical answer that shows how to create a wrapper class for Graphics2D and use it, as is described in the OP's link.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a Proxy. It lets you wrap all of the functionality of Graphics2D without needing to code each method.

The GraphicsView interface declares the additional functionality:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public interface GraphicsView {
    void setViewport(Rectangle r);
    Rectangle getViewport();
    boolean isViewportActive();
    void setViewportActive(boolean active);
}
```

The Graphics2DWrapperFactory a proxy to Graphics2D + GraphicsView:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class Graphics2DWrapperFactory {
    public static Graphics2D wrapGraphics2D(final Graphics2D g) {
        GraphicsView gv = new GraphicsView() {
            // Implement new functionality here...
            private boolean active;
            Rectangle r;
            @Override
            public Rectangle getViewport() {
                System.err.println("getViewport called");
                return r;
            }
            @Override
            public void setViewport(Rectangle r) {
                this.r = r;
                System.err.println("setViewport called");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isViewportActive() {
                System.err.println("isViewportActive called");
                return active;
            }
            @Override
            public void setViewportActive(boolean active) {
                this.active = active;
                System.err.println("setViewportActive called");
            }
        };
        InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new GraphicsWrapperInvocationHandler(g, gv);
        Class<?> interfaces[] = { Graphics2D.class, GraphicsView.class};
        return (Graphics2D) Proxy.newProxyInstance(g.getClass().getClassLoader(), interfaces, invocationHandler);
    }
    private static class GraphicsWrapperInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        private final GraphicsView gv;
        private final Graphics2D g2d;
        public GraphicsWrapperInvocationHandler(Graphics2D g, GraphicsView gv) {
            this.g2d = g;
            this.gv = gv;
        }
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            String methodName = method.getName();
            switch(methodName) {
                // If the is calling one of the GraphicsView methods, delegate to gv
                case "setViewport":
                case "getViewport":
                case "isViewportActive":
                case "setViewportActive":
                    return method.invoke(gv, args);
                // Otherwise, it's a Graphics2D methods. Delegate to g2d
                default:
                    return method.invoke(g2d, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```